# Javascript statement with || {};

Tags: javascript

Im studying javascript and today I found this code :

```
window.Picture2 = window.Picture2 || {};
```

I dont understand the || {} ;
Can someone explain this for me? Tks so much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a dangerous way to assign a default value to a global variable `Picture2`.

```
window.Picture2 = window.Picture2 || {};
```

This will initialize `window.Picture2` as a new Object `{}` if it is not defined. **However** since this is a check for truthyness, `Picture2` also will be assigned an empty object if it has any of these [falsy values](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/):

```
// these are all falsy
0, NaN, null, '', undefined, false
```

which might not be the desired behaviour for all these cases, especially for the `0`, `NaN`, `false` or `''` Value.

**EDIT**
The `??` "NULLISH COALESCING" operator is now part of the [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CoalesceExpression) standard and has [pretty decent browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing) already.

So the syntax for your use case would be:

```
window.Picture2 ?? {};
```

This will evaluate to false if `Picture2` equals `undefined` or `null`, but not for the rest of the falsy values.

If you want to assign a default value for a function parameter, you can now also write the following:

```
function myfunc(Picture2 = {}){
   /* function body */
}
```

Both, the default parameter syntax and the nullish coalescing operator are the only correct ways to assign default values without side effects.

Comment: +1 And wouldn't it be better to check `if (!window.Picture2) { window.picture2 = {} }`? The comparison need to be done in both cases but the re-assign could be skipped. Event though this code is slightly longer, it should be faster and for some people more readable.

Comment: @insertusernamehere this assignment * might* be internally optimised away, but nonetheless you are right, althoug still having the pitfall of the falsy values your code is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @insertusernamehere the save option is `if(typeof window.Picture2 != undefined){...}` - very verbose but one could put this into a `defined` function or something similar.

Comment: This is exactly how I would write it, only in Yoda Notation. :) I wanted to point out that a ternary operator might not be the best choice everywhere in addition to what you already said in your answer.

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yoda notation doesn't help you for older browsers since `undefined` was not write protected before ES5.

Comment: True that, but I write nearly all conditions this way to be consistent.

Answer (score 6):

It assigns a default empty object to `window.Picture2` if `window.Picture2` is undefined([falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/))

Comment: sadly not only when being `undefined`...

Comment: @Christoph that is why In `()` I said `falsy`

Comment: That's true, but it's the most important point to note when using this technique (see my answer)!

Comment: There is a proposal for ecmascript 6 to fill this gap with a default operator.

Answer (score 4):

It will check that `.Picture2` has been defined, if it has use that value, else assign `Window.Picture2` to a new object literal.

As @Christoph states - `Picture2` will be assigned a new object literal, if the object is `falsy`.

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: to be precise: if it is falsy - this includes `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It is read as :

> If **window.Picture2** is *undefined* or *null* assign empty object to
>   **window.Picture2**

Comment: empty json? what's that?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If the `window.Picture2` is undefined (false in a conditional evaluation) then the OR (`||`) is exectuted and the `window.Picture2` becomes an empty object.